# re-estimating confidence of C5.0 rules using another dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction, r-caret

Context: I have fitted a `glmnet` to my data. But for operational reason we would actually like to have rule-set. So I then fitted a `C5.0Rules` model to the *predicted* class from my `glmnet`. i.e. the `C5.0Rules` is essentially approximating my `glmnet`. However, as a result, the `C5.0Rules` will report a very high confidence (and other performance metrics), because its target is easy. A natural approach to correct this is to re-estimate the confidence (and other performance metrics) using the real response, or another dataset. But I need to do this so that the model remembers this new confidence, so in the future, it will report the corrected confidence level along with the prediction. How do I do that?

Reproducible example:

```
library(glmnet)
library(C50)
library(caret)

data(churn)

## original glmnet
glmnet=train(churn~.-state-area_code-international_plan-voice_mail_plan,data=churnTrain,method="glmnet")

## only retain useful predictors
temp=varImp(glmnet)$importance
reducedVar=rownames(temp)[temp>0]
churnTrain2=data.frame(churnTrain[,match(reducedVar,colnames(churnTrain))],
                      prediction=fitted(glmnet))

## fit my C5.0 which approximates the glmnet prediction
C5=train(prediction~.,data=churnTrain2,method="C5.0Rules")
summary(C5) ## notice the high confidence and performance measure.
```

(An alternative approach I can think of is to get `C5.0` to predict the predicted *probability* instead of class, but this turns it into a regression problem so I won't be able to use `C5.0`)